# PrimeFaces SelectCheckBoxmenu showing old value after clearing

Tags: primefaces

In my JSF view I have a p:selectCheckboxMenu and CLEAR button. The aim of that CLEAR button is that when a user clicks the button, all selected checkbox values are removed and enable the checkbox again.Am writing the logic in JAVA side to update the changes by using requestcontext update method.But for my logic its not working.

```
JAVA :
public void clearResource{
   getRemove_resource_SelectionList().clear();
   enDis_resourceSelection(false);
   RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("ResourceSelection");
```

}

```html
<p:outputLabel id="ResourceSelection">Resource</p:outputLabel>
<p:selectCheckboxMenu  id="selectUnselectresource" filter="true"
    filterMatchMode="contains" multiple="true"
    value="#{Bean.remove_resource_SelectionList}"
    disabled="#{Bean.enDis_resourceSelection}">
   
    <f:selectItems value="#{Bean.resource_List}" var="resource"
        itemLabel="#{resource.attribute}" itemValue="#{resource.attr_value}"/>
        
    <p:ajax event="change" update="@this"
        onstart="PF('PM_progress').block();" oncomplete="PF('PM_progress').unblock();"  />
    <p:ajax event="toggleSelect" update="@this"
        onstart="PF('PM_progress').block();" oncomplete="PF('PM_progress').unblock();"  />
</p:selectCheckboxMenu>


<p:commandButton value="Clear" style="margin-top:10px;margin-right:5px; 
    id="ClearButton"
    actionListener="#{Bean.clear_Resource()}" immediate="true"
    onstart="PF('PM_progress').block();"
    oncomplete="PF('PM_progress').unblock();"/>
```

Comment: See [ask] and [mcve]... (dit you not encounter these when taking the [tour] when you subscribed?

Comment: So if you create a new clean jsf project with primefaces in it and you copy just this code in there, does it compile? Run? So it is not a 'reproducible' piece of code. Please improve